# TypeError when comparing Numpy array of dtype datetime64 with Pandas Timestamp object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, timestamp

I have the following np.array `times` that I want to compare against a reference variable `end = Timestamp('2016-10-31 21:00:00')`, which is indexed from a `datetime64[ns]` column in a Pandas DataFrame.

```
times = np.array(['2016-10-31T20:17:46.000', '2016-10-31T20:28:45.000',
                  '2016-11-01T08:13:07.000', '2016-11-01T08:35:34.000'],
                   dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

(To clarify, running `type(end)` yields `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`)

Executing `times >= end` yields the following error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and
> 'int'

but `times[0] >= end`, `times[1] >=end`,... correctly returns `False`, `False`, `True`, and `True`, respectively.

Currently my workaround is to execute `times >= end.to_datetime64()`, but I'm curious about why there's a difference between vectorized and element-by-element comparison between these timestamp objects. I am using Numpy 1.18.5 and Pandas 1.0.3.

Comment: `times = pd.to_datetime('times')` It needs to *specifically* be in pandas datetime fromat. You need to use `pd.to_datetime()` Keep that in mind when comparing pandas datetime to anything in date/time fromat that is not pandas.

Comment: ...or just construct `times = pd.to_datetime(['2016-10-31T20:17:46.000', ...])`